# Transform this into a flat surface

Tags: modeling

How can i transform this sphere into a flat terrain with the pattern of the sphere ?

[image: el]

Comment: you mean you want to make an animation of it unfolding/flattening?

Comment: No, i want this Sphere to be like terrain

Comment: a terrain with the same kind of geometry?

Comment: A flat surface with the pattern that the sphere has

Comment: ok so perhaps edit your question to make it more understandable  ;)

Comment: I'm not sure it's even possible, what's possible in 3D won't be on a flat terrain, or it will be distorted like a map of the earth if you see what I mean

Comment: I only want that a plane has the same pattern/texture as the sphere

Comment: He wants the terrain to have the same topology.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways of doing this:

1. [Use that sphere for knife project tool](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J0lA9iJxnlM)

   - Cut the sphere in half in Edit Mode
   - Choose Top View
   - In Object mode select your sphere, and then select the pane
   - Go into Edit Mode and Knife Project
2. Collapse the sphere

   - Cut the sphere in half in Edit Mode
   - Select all vertices
   - Scale it along the Z axis to 0 (On a keyboard: S + Z + 0)

I am quite new to Blender myself, but in my experience, these are the two easy ways of achieving it.